# annotations in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I'd like to convert this SimpleFormController to use the annotation support introduced in Spring MVC 2.5

**Java**

```
public class PriceIncreaseFormController extends SimpleFormController {

    ProductManager productManager = new ProductManager();

    @Override
    public ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command)
            throws ServletException {

        int increase = ((PriceIncrease) command).getPercentage();
        productManager.increasePrice(increase);

        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()));
    }

    @Override
    protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)
            throws ServletException {
        PriceIncrease priceIncrease = new PriceIncrease();
        priceIncrease.setPercentage(20);
        return priceIncrease;
    }

}
```

**Spring Config**

```
<!-- Include basic annotation support -->
<context:annotation-config/>        

<!-- Comma-separated list of packages to search for annotated controllers. Append '.*' to search all sub-packages -->
<context:component-scan base-package="springapp.web"/>  

<!-- Enables use of annotations on controller methods to map URLs to methods and request params to method arguments  -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

<bean name="/priceincrease.htm" class="springapp.web.PriceIncreaseFormController">
    <property name="sessionForm" value="true"/>
    <property name="commandName" value="priceIncrease"/>
    <property name="commandClass" value="springapp.service.PriceIncrease"/>
    <property name="validator">
        <bean class="springapp.service.PriceIncreaseValidator"/>
    </property>
    <property name="formView" value="priceincrease"/>
    <property name="successView" value="hello.htm"/>
    <property name="productManager" ref="productManager"/>
</bean>
```

Basically, I'd like to replace all the XML configuration for the `/priceincrease.htm` bean with annotations within the Java class. Is this possible, and if so, what are the corresponding annotations that I should use?

Thanks,
Don

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It'll look something like the following, although whether it works or not exactly as is will depend a bit on your configuration (view resolver, etc).  I should also note that there are about eight billion valid ways to write this thing.  See the Spring documentation, [13.11.4 "Supported handler method arguments and return types"](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments) for an overview of the insanity.  Also note that you can autowire the validator

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/priceincrease.htm")
public class PriceIncreaseFormController {

    ProductManager productManager;

    @Autowired
    public PriceIncreaseFormController(ProductManager productManager) {
        this.productManager = productManager;
    }

    // note: this method does not have to be called onSubmit
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("priceIncrease") PriceIncrease priceIncrease, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status {

        new PriceIncreaseValidator().validate(priceIncrease, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "priceincrease";
        }
        else {
            int increase = priceIncrease.getPercentage();
            productManager.increasePrice(increase);
            status.setComplete();
            return "redirect:hello.htm";
        }
    }

    // note: this method does not have to be called setupForm
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)    
    public String setupForm(Model model) {
        PriceIncrease priceIncrease = new PriceIncrease();
        priceIncrease.setPercentage(20);
        model.addAttribute("priceIncrease", priceIncrease);
        return "priceincrease";
    }

}
```

Comment: It's those eight billion valid ways that I despise and I usually just end up implementing Controller directly - at least then I can trace the interface as appropriate.  Both the annotations and the form controller hierarchy are confusing IMO.

Comment: The key thing to me is that the annotation based controllers can be unit tested a lot easier than the ones using the old class hierarchy. Of course it takes time to get used to it. Another feature I wouldn't wanna miss anymore is the ability to extend the method parameter injection but the testing thing is the ost ovious one to me.

Answer (score 0):

Someone completed this project with a recent MVC and it's on github, so you can see how all the classes are changed compared to Spring's tutorial.

Link: [PriceIncreaseFormController](https://github.com/bogus/Java-Spring-Examples/blob/master/spring-mvc-jpa/src/main/java/com/medratech/spring/mvc/web/PriceIncreaseFormController.java)